# Doesn't work Rebind Method in the Telerik schedule component

Tags: c#, blazor, telerik, telerik-scheduler

I want to refresh the Telerik schedule component.
For that, I used this link: https://docs.telerik.com/blazor-ui/components/scheduler/refresh-data

But, In my code doesn't work Rebind Method,

I can see this problem:

[image]

Then I also try a sample code in the above link in my code (by copying and pasting). doesn't work. It generates the same issues.

Please help me!!
Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you are using the latest version of the telerik balzor components package. Likely yours is old and does not have this feature

Comment: The Rebind() method of the Telerik UI Scheduler is exposed with the 3.6.0 version of the product. Therefore, using an older version will result in a compile-time error.